# "That will have to" vs "Which will have to"

Tags: phrasing, which-that

I am not really sure if this sentence is translated correctly into English :

> *Access keys have been researched and the implementation will be done in a future sprint, that will have something to do with GUI.*

1. Is the use of the word "*that*" in this sentence correct?
2. Can I, or should I, exchange "*that*" for "*which*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Access keys have been researched, the implementation will be done in a future sprint which will have something to do with GUI*

I would also think about swapping "*have something to do with*" for "*pertain to*"